# Hiding view and controller name completely in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

Is there any way to hide the controller and action name completely in MVC.
(eg) localhost:81 should always remain same even on clicking any of the action in controller.
i.e., localhost:81/Controller/Action should not happen.

Comment: you can achieve this by using SPA architect, you will have only one page and all the actions will get called by ajax, hope that this will help you

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you don't have to use the controller and action name in the URL. That's just the default. You can always define your own custom routes and make any URL you want hit any controller action you want. This is even easier if you use attribute routing, available in MVC5 or via the Nuget package, AttributeRouting, in lesser versions. This allows you to customize the URL for each action explicitly right on the action definition, which again can be any URL you want.

However, if you're truly looking to have just your domain as the only URL period, then @HadiHassan is correct in suggesting a SPA (single page application) architecture. There's many ways to go about this, so you'll need to just do some research to determine which set of tooling meets your needs best. At one point there was a project template for an SPA app in Visual Studio, it inexplicably disappeared for a time, and I believe it has now returned in the latest web tooling for Visual Studio. However, it's not hard to start from scratch.

You'll most likely want two projects, a Web API and a basic website project. The Web API is to provide your backend connectivity and is where you'll end up connecting to your databases and such, with something like [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/) to provide the connectivity on the client-side (your website project). There's alternatives here though, as you can also easily opt for a backend like a Node.js, which then wouldn't even require ASP.NET at all.

Since a SPA pretty much moves the entire application over to the client-side, you'll want to lean on a robust full-stack JS library. [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) is a popular choice, and has support for all the stuff like controllers, routing, etc. that you lose from a server-side MVC application.